# Confused on Symfony2 YAML imports

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm new to Symfony and a little confused by the `imports` key found at the top of `config.yml`. I am trying to import `/our_stuff/admin/version.yml` into Symfony's `config.yml` file.

This is what my `config.yml` file looks like:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: '/our_stuff/admin/version.yml' }
```

This is what I have inside my `version.yml` file

```
version:
  last_recorded_software_version: '10.12.1'
```

But this produces the error:

```
FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/our_stuff/admin/version.yml" from "/our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/config/config.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "last_recorded_software_version" (in /our_stuff/admin/version.yml). 
    Looked for namespace "last_recorded_software_version", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution")
```

To test, I've also moved the `version.yml` file into Symfony's config folder. The path is `symfony_root/app/config/`, but this still produces the same error.

Why does importing work for the default YAML files that are included in Symfony, but not the one's I include?

**EDIT** Edited for clarity

**Edit 2** Here is the entirety of the `/our_stuff/admin/version.yml` file:

```
# Update this variable ONLY RIGHT BEFORE creating a new numbered release 
version:
  last_recorded_software_version: '10.12.1'
```

**Edit 3** The solution:

The version.yml file needs to have a namespace of `parameters` in order to read them in the `config.yml` file

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: 'parameters.yml' }
    - { resource: '/etc/sites/mysite.com/parameters.yml' }





#/etc/sites/mysite.com/version.yml
parameters:
   some_key:
      some_other_key: value
      some_other_key1: value
      ...
```

Comment: Your imported parameters file needs to be namespaced as `parameters` where as you seem to have `last_recorded_software_version` at the root namespace.

Comment: What is your question? What do you place in your YAML files? What is wrong?

Comment: Hey sorry, I worded the question badly. I'm tying to import ```version.yml``` into ```config.yml```. In ```version.yml``` I have the ```last_recorded_software_version``` key namespaced under ```version:```. Is that correct? It's still giving me an error even with the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your configuration files outside the project direcoty or in project directory and can include check this link [global-configuration-files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html#global-configuration-files)

You can include you configuration file like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: 'parameters.yml' }
    - { resource: '/etc/sites/mysite.com/parameters.yml' }
```

Your version.yml file format should be:

```
parameters:
   some_key:
      some_other_key: value
      some_other_key1: value
      ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, however, I still get the error ```FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/our_stuff/admin/version.yml" from "/our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/config/config.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "version" (in /our_stuff/admin/version.yml). Looked for namespace "version", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution")```

Comment: can you post you version.yml file to review it. I think problem is in you configuration rather than the way you are importing it.

Comment: I made an edit to the original question posting the entirety of my ```version.yml``` file

Comment: Updated my answer now please add parameters: in your yml and try it.

Answer (score 1):

All config files in Symfony are parsed by Configuration component. Symfony application by default import only one file: `config_%environment%.yml`. This file has 3 predefined sections that have significant value for Symfony:

- imports

  Contain array of resources that will be imported by configuration component in processing. These resources may be `xml`, `yml` or even `php` files that will return array.
- services

  Contain service definitions that have very significant value for ServiceContainer that will create services from this config section.
- parameters

  Parameters that will have significant value for ServiceContainer that will manage all included values in parameters section of container. If you want to get parameters from service container you should define it here.

Also you can import any config file in your bundle's configuration class.

If you import your config files inside **imports** block or in your bundle's Configuration class you should place them in appropriate sections: **parameters**, **services**.

As was requested examples:

**parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    param: value1
    array: {key1: value2}
```

**services.yml**:

```
services:
    class: FQCN/To/Your/Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your version.config under some bundle you have to import it like this :

```
- { resource: "@AAA/YourBundle/Resources/config/version.yml" }
```

Otherwise your first import will work perfectly :

```
- { resource: version.yml }
```

Comment: Can I import a yaml file outside of the Symfony project? Say if it's stored in  /home/user? Or does it have to be inside of the Symfony project

Comment: It's not a proper way to link to a local file in your symfony project , i think that your file should be some way under your project so when you deploy your application under other server the file remain accessible.

Comment: I get the same error when I try to use ```- { resource: version.yml }```. I move the ```version.yml``` file to the same folder ```config.yml```. The path is: ```symfony_project/app/config/```. The error is still ```FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/config/version.yml" from "/our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/config/config.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "version" (in /our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/config/version.yml). Looked for ```